# Verbose exception with service operation

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm using C# to build a service operation. When something goes wrong, I want to throw an exception that could be catch client side.

However, when an exception is thrown the client is only able to get a generic error like "400: bad request" and the exception message is not accessible.

In my service operation, I have enabled verbose errors with this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
and
config.useVerboseErrors = true;
```

I also unpack the TargetInvocationException and instead return a DataServiceException with this function:

```
    protected override void HandleException(HandleExceptionArgs args)
    {
        // Handle exceptions raised in service operations.
        if (args.Exception.GetType() == typeof(TargetInvocationException)
            && args.Exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            if (args.Exception.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(DataServiceException))
            {
                // Unpack the DataServiceException.
                args.UseVerboseErrors = true;
                args.Exception = args.Exception.InnerException as DataServiceException;
            }
            else
            {
                // Return a new DataServiceException as "400: bad request."
                args.UseVerboseErrors = true;
                args.Exception = new DataServiceException(400, args.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I use the browser, I can see the verbose exception message, but when I try programmatically, the inner exception is null and I only see the generic error message "400: bad request".

Strangely, if I return a code 200 instead of 400, I can see the exception message in the answer body. But obviously I don't want to do this.

So, is there a way to get the exception message client side, when you throw an exception from a service operation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [end to end tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738749.aspx)? Furthermore, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx) MSDN page isn't as daunting as it may first seem, and i think the "Provide Additional Information When an Exception Occurs" section would be useful to you. Have a lovely read.